# javascript function execute after a variable got value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can function be executed after some variable got value (or changed) in JavaScript?
In my example, the `variable` is hoisted at first which is declared to be a global, then will assign some value to it in `getData()` function.

I have tried using `.delay()` method, but i don't know how much time the ajax needs.

briefly describe:

1) Declaring `variable`

2) calling `getData()` function, then assign the data to variable

3) calling `funcA()` function

4) calling `funcB()` function and pass function `doSomething()` as a callback in `funcA()`

5) calling the callback function in `funcB()`

6) log the data in `doSomething()`

```
<script>
    var variable;
    variable = getData();
    funcA();

    function funcA() {
      funcB(doSomething);

      function doSomething(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    }

    function funcB(callback) {
      if (variable !== undefined) {//it is obviously undefined.
        callback(variable);
      }
    }
    </script>

    //another js file
    <script>
    function getData() {
      //get data by using ajax
      //i don't know how much time it needs.
      return data;
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: You already seem to know about callbacks - the most correct answer to this problem will be to pass a callback to your ajax mechanism for it to call when it's done.

Comment: why not just calling everything you need to do after the assignment.

Comment: @Roozbeh hz  i have update my example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Your edit makes it a dupe of the linked question - in that it shows how to use callbacks to return information back.  Essentially you'll need to pass a callback function as a parameter to `getData()`.

Answer (score 0):

change your getdata to this:

```
function getData() {
    $.ajax({
    url: "some url",
    success: function(result){
        variable = result;
        //do everything that should be done here or call your callback
    });
}
```